# Installation of asyncio and asyncssh on python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-asyncio

I want to run multiple `ssh` connections using `python2.7`,`asyncio`and `asyncssh`. Trying to find out how to install these packages, I came to know that my `python` version should be `python3` or above and that I need to install `trollius` to run `asyncio` functions using `python2.7`.  If I need to use `asyncssh` functions using `python2.7`, what are the steps I should follow, any dependencies I need to take care of?

Comment: `Asyncssh` has been written for Python 3.4+. I doubt it will run on 2.7.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 7):

`asyncssh` needs Python 3.4+, what strictly [specified](https://github.com/ronf/asyncssh) in it's requirements.

`trollius` is not a full replacement for `asyncio` and can't be used for most `asyncio` based modules you might need in your project.

So, if you're going to start new project with `asyncio` (and `asyncssh`), it's a good chance to start it [using](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) Python 3.

Comment: I wonder why channels is supported by Python27 but , when run the server, it says it need asyncio which is not available for Python27.

Comment: @ArindamRoychowdhury For cross-compatibility maybe?  This way you can (if they did it right) still use an ASGI server to run your program regardless of whether it's PY2 or PY3.  On the other hand, maybe it's just an oversight :p